# How do/can I run a select SQL statement inside an if?

Tags: sql-server-2005, syntax, insert

I'm having trouble finding the syntax for a statement (or whether or not it's even possible).

We're running SQL Server 2005, and I'd like to do something like:

`IF ((SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE userid = 'myid' AND value = 3) < 1) then INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('myid', 3)`

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IF ((SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE userid = 'myid' AND value = 3) < 1)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('myid', 3)
END
```

[IF/ELSE reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933214%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

or you could use NOT EXISTS

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE userid = 'myid' AND value = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @COUNT int

SET @COUNT=(SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE userid = 'myid' AND value = 3)
IF (@COUNT < 1)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('myid', 3)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to do it in a single statement:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT 'myid', 3
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE userid = 'myid' AND value = 3) < 1
```